# CloudKit Zone CKSubscriptionOptions

Tags: cloudkit, ios9

I am getting an error setting up a zone subscription for a custom zone.

```
let mainZoneID=CKRecordZoneID(zoneName: "MainZone", ownerName: CKOwnerDefaultName)

let subscription=CKSubscription(zoneID: mainZoneID, options: CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordCreation)
```

The error message I get says "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'CKSubscriptionTypeRecordZone subscriptions are incompatible with subscription options 1'"

I found a [link](http://redwolftech.blogspot.com/2015/05/got-it-twice.html) that shows the use of `CKSubscriptionOptions.allZeros` but that is not an option in the iOS 9 SDK at least.

The Apple docs reference setting it to 0 but when I do that, it will not compile.

From the docs: "The configuration options for the subscription. You must specify 0 for this parameter. Zone subscriptions currently do not support any options."

See code snippet below:

```
let subscription=CKSubscription(zoneID: mainZoneID, options: 0)
```

The compiler error says I can not use an Int for an option. Does anyone know how to setup a zone subscription on a custom zone?  Is this a bug?

Comment: zone's are only allowed in the private database. Is that what you use?

Comment: @EdwinVermeer Yes, I am using the private database, with a zone named "MainZone"

Comment: Have you tried CKSubscriptionOptions(rawValue:0)

Comment: @EdwinVermeer, I have not tried that, I will try it later today and let you know if it works.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer, I tried your suggestion: `subscription = CKSubscription(zoneID: "MainZone", options: CKSubscriptionOptions(rawValue:0) )` but that still gives me a compiler error "Cannot find an initializer for type 'CKSubscription' that accepts an argument list of type '(zoneID: String, options: CKSubscriptionOptions)'"

Comment: @EdwinVermeer, Your suggestion above did work...  I had the zone name in there when I tried it earlier instead of the zoneID.  This worked: `subscription = CKSubscription(zoneID: mainZoneID, options: CKSubscriptionOptions(rawValue:0) )` .  Thanks for your help.  If you change this to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the CKSubscriptionOptions enum does not have an option for 0. You can force a value of 0 by using CKSubscriptionOptions(rawValue:0)